# Adding Context to Navbar HTML Django Project

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add context to `navbar.html` but it is not rendering/ showing the required information.

Here is the models.py:

```
class Information(models.Model):
    github = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

here is the view.py:

```
#Trial 1
def home(request):
    template_name = 'blog/navbar.html'
    info = Information.objects.first()
    context = {
        'info': info,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)

#Trial 2
class Home(DetailView):
    model = Information
    template_name = 'blog/navbar.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'info'
```

Here is the HTML:

```
          <a href="" class="nav-link waves-effect">{{info.facebook}}
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
          </a>
```

**My Qustion:**
Why is the `{{info.facebook}}` not printing what am I missing? How should I fix it?
In the URLs I did not add anything because I am sending the context to navbar which will be appearing on every page not a specific page

Comment: Are you sure that info.facebook is not null?

Comment: @EPaul Yes i added a link to facebook just as an example

Answer (score 0):

Because no query was executed, try

```
info = Information.objects.all().first()
```

Comment: Print 'info' in the view and check the server console to see what is the issue

Comment: Nothing is printed in the console. i used the home function not the class based view as if noting is triggering the home function to run